# RadioGroup data binding and dynamic responses

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I would like to create an Android RadioGroup with data driven/dynamic RadioButtons. The String values to be created as RadioButtons and the selected response would utilize data binding.

Ideally this would function similar to the Spinner widget, where possible values are passed in via entries:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@{data.possibleValues}" />
```

To accomplish this, I was thinking I could extend RadioGroup to provide it with a similar `entries` attribute, which would be used to create each of the RadioButtons as part of the group. This would also need an `onClick()` callback somewhere to handle changes in selection.